# avoid multi table relationship with one row table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a question about hibernate constrains, about one issue that I never had before.
Imagine that I have a table(Snapshot) where I can add some snapshot rows, which every single one have to be related with just one row of another tables. But this relationship is not only with one table, multiple tables can join with this snapshot table. But I want to prevent that once one row of snapshot is already link with another row table let´s say:

```
A.row1->Snapshot.row1
```

It´s not possible that another table pick up the same row for his relationship

```
B.row1->Snapshot.row1.
```

Because if dont, imagine the issue when I´m trying to do a delete on cascade on A.

Any idea how to make this work with hibernate unique constraints

Answer (score -1):

in Snapshot make the field that links to the other table (i suppose it's called row1) unique.

```
@Column(unique = true)
```

edit:
you can not control how many other tables are using your primary key. what you can do is introduce a new table where you manage your linking. there you coudl have to columns one called link_from and the other one link_to and make link_to unique.

Comment: is the id, and it´s already unique because is autoincremental. the problem is control that no more that one table can make this link. A->Snapshot.id B->Snapshot.id

Comment: that is impossible. you would have to introduce an additionl table where you hold those links. e.g. a table called linker and there you make the column linkto (your snapshot.row1) unique.